# Edittext adds whitespace automatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have very strange behavior with Edittext, when I wrote some text in 1st Edittext, then selected 2d Edittext, returned to 1st and wrote some text, dot, some text(ololo.o lolo) automaticaly adds whitespace after first character, I had not such problem before and I can not find the reason of it, can someone help me to resolve this problem?

This is my layout

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edEmail"
    style="@style/BlackLight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:hint="@string/email_hint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:maxEms="64"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edMessage"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_14" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edMessage"
    style="@style/BlackLight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/message_hint"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxEms="512"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:minHeight="150dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_14" />
```

This is my java class:

```
public class FeedbackFragment extends BaseFragment{

private OnFeedback callback;

private EditText edEmail;
private EditText edMessage;
private ImageView btnSendFeedback;

public static FeedbackFragment newInstance() {
    return new FeedbackFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feedback, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof OnFeedback) {
        callback = (OnFeedback) context;
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement " + OnFeedback.class.getName());
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    btnSendFeedback = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSendFeedback);
    edEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edEmail);
    edMessage = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edMessage);
    edEmail.requestFocus();

    btnSendFeedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (callback != null) {
                SearchBar.Utils.hideInputMethod(edEmail);
                callback.sendFeedBack(edEmail.getText().toString(), edMessage.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    open();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    close();
}

public interface OnFeedback{
    boolean sendFeedBack(String email, String message);
}

public void open(){
    Utils.showInputMethod(edEmail);
}

public void close(){
    Utils.hideInputMethod(edEmail);
}}
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: @DeepakSachdeva I added layout file to my question

Comment: I checked it at my end, worked fine for me. have you done anything in .java class?

Comment: @DeepakSachdeva I added my java class, but I do not do something special in it

Comment: It might have been added by your keyboard. Some keyboards try to be smart and insert spaces because it thinks you might be starting a new sentence.

Comment: I think that this is not good behavior when keyboard adds some character into my input string, I am using Nexus 5x and problem happens here but on device with android 4.4.2 no

Comment: check your keyboard behaviour. it may auto add whitespace on certain condition..

Answer (score 0):

If anyone lands here.
Swiftkey keyboard adds whitespace after a dot. This is really terrible and my EditText supposed to take in websites like apple.com, but it adds whitespace after apple. and it messes the experience. I solved it by setting inputType to TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS. See if this helps in your case.